# AndroidStudio run application without activities

Tags: android, widget, android-studio

My application is homescreen widget and it doesn't have any activities, in Eclipse I just press "run" button and it installs app on my debugging device without starting it (no activities - nothing to start). But here, in AndroidStudio button "run" even not enabled. What should I do to test my app on device?

Comment: Did you create run/debug configuration?

Comment: Thank you, it seems that android studio doesn't create run configuration automatically if there's no launcher activity, you could post it as answer and I'll mark it as accepted to close the question

Comment: As you wish ;) Answer has been placed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA so you need to create at least one run/debug configuration to send your application to the virtual or real device.